# Unable to disable app rotation in Multi-Window (split-screen) mode, Android

Tags: android, orientation, android-configchanges, multi-window, split-screen

First of all, here are things I've done so far: **(1)** I handle screen rotation, orientation changes and Multi-Window related config changes inside my application. **(2)** I forbid all kinds of `configChanges`:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout
```

Everything works just as intended, well until **I enable screen-rotation from Android settings in Multi-Window mode..** When I do so, my app starts rotating inside its split-screen portion as if I enabled orientation, which I did not enable, hence my `configChanges` parameter above states.

*Don't get me wrong, I don't mind the second app (in the side window) to rotate, yet I want to handle my own app rotation in my own portion of the split-screen..*

I recon this problem might seem a bit strange, but I'm open for any suggestions. Maybe, you've got an idea or had a similar issue before.. any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to handle this use case?

Comment: @BATMAN no, unfortunately had to disable multiwindow